# Can't Build QBExampleConsumerSite in MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I receive the following errors when trying to Build the Web Site...

Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the namespace 'ExampleConsumerSite' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Sites\QBExampleConsumerSite\ViewData.aspx.cs 35 27 C:...\QBExampleConsumerSite\

Error 2 The type or namespace name 'OAuthPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Sites\QBExampleConsumerSite\ViewData.aspx.cs 39 35 C:...\QBExampleConsumerSite\

Error 3 The type or namespace name 'OAuthPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Sites\QBExampleConsumerSite\Default.aspx.cs 34

I'm using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.  I have QB Pro 2011 installed on a Win 7 PC.

I have added DevDefined.OAuth.dll, DevDefined.OAuth.Wcf.dll, and Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.dll to the Project's references.

I must still be missing something but cannot figure out what.

Comment: I believe I figured it out.  I had opened the sample files as a web site and not as a project solution.  Once I opened it the correct way, I was able to build and run the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. I had opened the sample files as a web site and not as a project solution. Once I opened it the correct way, I was able to build and run the project.